# A question on word stress

Tags: conversation, american-accent, accent, word-stress, intonation

[Video link:stress](https://sendvid.com/r96aqlrg)

It seems that two stresses are put in the following words in the video and all of the main stress are on the second syllable because the pitch is higher and rises on the second one.

1. ,plan'ning
2. ,mur'der
3. ,my'stery

[image]
The above is the pitch contour from PRAAT.

Is this normal to converse with such an intonation?

By the way, which syllable is stressed on "online" by the lady in the video? Do native speakers of English say it in such an intonation ?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

All those words have primary stress on the first syllable.

The word "online" is emphasised for contrast, the speaker wants to emphasise that this party is *online* and not in person and so emphasises the word.

The general style of speaking is overly careful and clear, it is clearly being read from a script to be easily understood by learners.